# Force a certain footnote-number in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I have created a footnote on slide 10 of my presentation. This very same slide reappears on slide 12. On slide 11 though I had to include a different slide. Now, on slide 12 the same slide as on slide 10 appears, simply the text has a different color. I want the footnote to be the same (footnote [1]), but LaTeX has increased it, because it is viewed as a different slide.

Is there a way to force the footnote number to be a [1] ? 
On a different slide, I am using another footnote, which I want to have the number [2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually intervene with the footnote numbering, you could use `\againframe` to show again a given slide and it will automatically have the same footnote number than in its first incarnation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=foo]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item marmot
    \item<alert@2> duck
    \end{itemize}
    \footnote{reapearing slide}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\footnote{some other slide with a foonote}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx, samcarter! But is there a way to change the color of one bullet-point using `\againframe{}` ?

Comment: @user503842 sure, give me a second

Comment: @user503842 please see my updated example

Comment: great, that's what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user503842 You're welcome!